# CA1819: Properties should not return arrays. Does this happen only with arrays? If yes, why?

Tags: c#, array

I have a question about CA1819 msdn performance warning.

The rule is: Arrays returned by properties are not write-protected, even if the property is read-only. To keep the array tamper-proof, the property must return a copy of the array. Typically, users will not understand the adverse performance implications of calling such a property. Specifically, they might use the property as an indexed property.

I understand the rule.

I want to know if this happens only with arrays? If yes, why?

Answer (score 7):

Arrays are reference types. That is when a property returns an array object it's returning a pointer/reference to it's internal array. The caller of the property can now modify that internal array (as they have a pointer to it), this is generally unwanted. To stop this you can return a copy of the internal array but now your doing a memory allocation and copy every time the property is used, and given that properties are meant to be light-weight that's not good.

This happens with any reference type that is mutable. If you have a private reference to a mutable reference type (Like a Stream, List or Dictionary) and you return that reference in a property than the caller can modify your data. If you have a value type (structs in C#) than they are always copied when they're returned from the property so the caller can't then modify your internal version of the data.

Comment: I would only note that making a copy of the array only protects the original array from tampering, not the new one.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/210444

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx). @ibasa. this article says that if collection are used (lists) then the problem can be fixed. And list is a reference type. Lets take an example 'code' private IDbCommand idbCommand;public IDbCommand Command
    {
      get
      {
        return idbCommand;
      }
    } when i try to change idbCommand from an outer class it does not allow me even though idCommand is a reference type.  Thanks

Comment: You can just return IEnumerable<T> because all arrays implement this interface and you won't be able to modify it without casting.

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/06/24/please-welcome-immutablearray.aspx

Comment: Yes, but the user can cast that back to an array and still be able to modify that, anyway i am asking for the reason why arrays are mutable when returned from a property, lets take another example, if we try returning a string with a getter method you wont be able to modify its value, but if you try to do that with an array with strings, you can change the values with ease.

Comment: It's true, but you can also call private methods with reflection.  If someone using your type wants to be tricky, finding trouble isn't hard.  IEnumerable probably better honors the contract if you don't need random access.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Is there any specific reason why only arrays can be modified? Other objects like string,list, IDbCommand etc. are not mutable. I think there is something that makes arrays mutable and other objects immutable, and that's what i am asking, do anyone know that reason?

Comment: @Kriss because arrays are mutable objects, strings aren't. Lists are mutable, as are many other objects there's nothing particularly special about arrays.

Comment: @Kriss it isn't just arrays, any reference type can be modified when returned from a property.  Strings are immutable by the language definition, no other type is.  You can certainly modify an IDbCommand if you return it from a property.  The warning is about the performance implications of returning a copy of an array through a property then some unsuspecting dev using it in a foreach thus causing a copy of the entire array on every step through the iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first off, .net has introduced IReadOnlyList and IReadOnlyDictionary which address this problem for generics(which is preferable to a base array), previously you would have to had created your own interface in order to see the same performance with the same restriction.

The basic problem, and no, it's not limited to arrays, is that you want to provide a method of accessing a bunch of items without requiring that they be iterated, but you don't want the consumer of your API to be adding or deleting items -- but previously all of the built in interfaces that allow what you want, also allowed what you don't want.

The suggested solution is both inefficient (creating a clone is slow) and misleading -- the consumer gets an array that he **thinks** he can modify and have that effect the object that returned it.  Ie he thinks if he adds an element and then calls the property again, he will get an array with p+1 items.  He also expects that o.ItemArray.Equals(o.ItemArray).  Neither of these expectations will be true.

As a practical problem, this is no longer a problem if you can use the right version of the framework and something other than an array.

As for the performance problem...

```
if(o.ItemArray.Equals(o.ItemArray) || o.ItemArray.Equals(o2.ItemArray))
```

Creates 4 copies of a potentially large array.

Edit in response to comment:

This is not a problem specific to Arrays. List and Dictionaries are also mutable.

```
IList<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("hello");
lst[0]="bye";
Console.WriteLine(lst[0]);
```

And the above code sample shows the problems with mutable list as properties.  Suppose that I had a class, Greetings, which had a list of words and phrases that you would use upon meeting someone.  Hello, Hi, Hola, Hey dude, Whats up! Como esta and so forth.  So, I have a property Words, and return the above lst.  You can then immediately execute the 3rd line and change my "hello" to "bye" --for everyone that has a reference to that instance of the class.

But as I said, in 4.5, you would get around this by having your list be IReadOnlyLst and, using this...

```
return (IReadOnlyList<string>) lst;
```

Comment: To have to make a copy of an array because arrays are mutable is one of the many defects of C# in my humble opinion.  Default behavior in a programming language should be efficient, not inefficient.

Comment: @Neil There are probably many performance-intensive C#, or C++, programs that use warning-inducing code all over the place, simply because of they're aware of the risks and know how to use them properly. Unless I've misinterpreted the warning mentioned, and it actually *refuses* to return the same-copy array, even with a warning.

Comment: @Neil Is there any specific reason why only arrays can be modified? Other objects like string,list, IDbCommand etc. are not mutable. I think there is something that makes arrays mutable and other objects immutable, and that's what i am asking, do anyone know that reason?

Comment: @Kriss It was a decision made when they were determining how C# would work.  I'm sure there are other objects which can be modified as well.  I suppose the main reason for making arrays mutable was to offer both options to the programmer.  I don't have a problem with alternatives, but the "default" should be the more efficient version in my humble opinion.

Comment: @jmoreno Yes you are right, lists are mutable too by index. But why can't we do the same thing with strings? What is the reason that string are not mutable? Can we say that only objects that can be accessed by index(array,list,etc) are mutable?

Comment: "string are not mutable" string's aren't mutable because they were designed that way. The designers could have made them mutable but they decided it was of more benefit for strings to be immutable. "Can we say that only objects that can be accessed by index(array,list,etc) are mutable?" NO!!! Lots of objects are mutable that don't have an indexer! Mutable just means the object can be modified in some way after creation. The random class doesn't have an indexer but its mutable because it changes state every time you call Next().

Comment: @Ibasa Sorry i formulated the question not in a proper way:The problem is that like in the example of the CA1819 we have a string array, and a property to get this array, but we don't have a setter method for that array. But only by using the get method we can modify its values by index. Can we say in general, that all the objects that can be accessed by index even if they don't have a set method can be modified? Tell me if i need to explain it more clearly.

Comment: No, because some objects only have a getter indexer not a setter indexer. Those objects can now be accessed by index, but the index can't be set so they are not modifiable. Your coming across as not fully understanding properties or the C# object model, I'd suggest you do more reading then come back here for clarification. Otherwise we're just going end up repeating all the documentation back to you.

Comment: @Neil: Making arrays immutable by default is not about efficiency.  Mutable arrays are very efficient, and have been the design choice for c-like languages since they were first invented. Copying an array to protect its original members is a programmer decision, but so is using a genuinely immutable array class instead (probably a better decision than copying).

Comment: @RobertHarvey So you tell me, is it better to make copying an array the default behavior for having an array returned in a property or would it be better to automatically have it immutable?  Sure, both could be used at any given point, but if your programmer colleague didn't understand the difference, would you prefer if he were copying the array or returning an immutable version?

Comment: @Neil: Neither of your choices is the expected default behavior in a C-like language.  Programmers can always copy an array or reach for an immutable collection if they need to.

Comment: @RobertHarvey We're talking about C#, not C, and you didn't answer my question.

Comment: What if making the array mutable won't cause any harm, should I blindly follow the guideline not to make property return an array?